# Google Search Results no longer has www in the sub-domain

Tags: google-search

I noticed today when I did a search for our site "mohavecounty" that the sub-domain www is missing from the links when I click on the result:

[image]

For example "Mohave County Jail", is now going to

```
https://mohavecounty.us/ContentPage.aspx?id=131&cid=81
```

instead of

```
https://www.mohavecounty.us/ContentPage.aspx?id=131&cid=81
```

Is there a way to fix this or is this the way Google is doing it now? I checked on Bing and it has the www subdomain on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site seems to be accessible via both www and non-www.
Usually (but not always) it would only be accessible via one or the other, with a 301 redirect in place to redirect to the preferred version of the domain name.

Make sure www is the preferred domain in Google Search Console (keep in mind though, this is only an indicator to Google as to which one should be indexed)
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en

and note the following at the bottom of the above linked page:

> Note: Once you've set your preferred domain, you may want to use a 301 redirect to redirect traffic from your non-preferred domain, so that other search engines and visitors know which version you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that it is working correctly externally from our site.  Internally is were its the problem (something to fix).  Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

You can actually tell Google which website version should they prioritize in displaying on the search results page. Check this out https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en. It might take some time for Google to update its database so be patient.